# PHP search 2 tables to show list

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am trying to show a page where in it will show a certain value 
and if not then it wont appear on a php

**table1**

```
|  id    | username |
|  21    |    box   | 
|  23    |    ace   |
|  25    |    cat   |
```

**ace** entered value in **table2** wherein it has his stamp there
as his *id* saved as **suid** and *username* to **spuname**
in

**table2**

```
|  sid   |  spuname |  suid   |
|   1    |    ace   |   23    |
|   2    |    box   |   21    |
|   3    |    cat   |   25    |
|   4    |    ace   |   23    |
|   5    |    ace   |   23    |
```

where suid is the session user ID

what Im trying to accomplish is if the user with **ace** name is *in session* / *logged in*
then it will show him values of table2 which only has his id and so as the others

here is for visualization.

---

**Page will show like this if its ace is logged in**

```
|  sid   |  spuname |  suid   |
|   1    |    ace   |   23    |
|   4    |    ace   |   23    |
|   5    |    ace   |   23    |

Entries = 3
```

**Page will show like this if its box is logged in**

```
|  sid   |  spuname |  suid   |
|   2    |    box   |   21    |

Entries = 1
```

it should show count value of **3**
only if it is ace who is on session.

---

**LOGIC:**

- search session id table1
- search posted values of table2 using logged in username
- show list and count on 1 page.

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should use query with [join](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/):

```
select table2.* from table2 inner join table1 on (table2.spuname = table1.username) where suid = X
```

Comment: I got this for count
`<?php  
  include('include/db.php');
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as spcount  
                     FROM sponsor where spuname = 'ace'");  
 if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error());
 }

 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
 {
    echo  $row['spcount'];
 }
 ?>`   but only working if its a fixed value `spuname = 'ace'`